# Accessing localhost from windows browser

Tags: python, cygwin, bottle

I am running python 2.7 + bottle on **cygwin** and I wanted to access a sample webpage from chrome.

I am unable to access the website running on `http://localhost:8080/hello` but when I do a curl within cygwin I am able to access it.

Error Message when accessing through Chrome

**Connection refused**
**Description: Connection refused**

Please let me know how I can access my local bottle website running inside Cygwin from windows  browser.

Comment: What error do you exactly get when you access `http://localhost:8080/hello` from your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you get a `connection refused` error, the best I can think of is that this is a browser issue. Try editing the LAN settings on your Chrome browser to bypass proxy server for local address.

Comment: yes. you are correct. I disabled Bypass Proxy server for local address and it worked correctly.